# Need to group the data using pandas based on months in the column data

Tags: python, pandas, datatables, dataset, pandas-groupby

I would like to group the data based on the month January and February. Here is a sample of the data set that I have.

```
   Date       Count

01.01.2019       1  
01.02.2019       7  
02.01.2019       4  
03.01.2019       4  
04.01.2019       1  
04.02.2019       5
```

I want to group the data as follows, where total count is summed up of count based on month 1(Jan) and 2(Feb):

```
Month  Total_Count
Jan       10
Feb       12
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. I am sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to datetime, group by the [`dt.month_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month_name.html) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
(df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
   .dt.month_name()
   .str[:3])['Count']
   .sum()
   .rename_axis('Month')
   .reset_index(name='Total_Count'))

  Month  Total_Count
0   Feb           12
1   Jan           10
```

---

To sort the index by month, we could instead do:

```
s = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date-'], format='%d.%m.%Y-').dt.month)['Count'].sum()
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s.index, format='%m').month_name().str[:3]
s.rename_axis('Month').reset_index(name='Total_Count')

  Month  Total_Count
0   Jan           10
1   Feb           12
```

Comment: I had a small doubt in this @yatu. How can i add a column to this dataframe by calling it in further code?

Comment: Usually it's not good practice @vishvam if you can avoid it better. The best way is to just calculate it once and that's it. appending to a df is not a good idea.